# wrap HTML tags in plain string with another HTML tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to wrap a HTML tag with another HTML tag in a string (so not a DOM element, a plain string). I created this function but I wonder if I could do it in one go without a forEach loop.

This is the working function:

```
function style(content) {
    var tempStyledContent = content;

    var imgMatches = tempStyledContent.match(/(<img.*?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>)/g);

    imgMatches.forEach(function (imgMatch) {
        var imgTag = imgMatch;
        var imgSrc = imgMatch.match(/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/)[1];

        tempStyledContent = tempStyledContent.replace(imgTag,
            "<a href=\"" + imgSrc + "\" data-fancybox>" + imgTag + "</a>");
    });

    return tempStyledContent;
}
```

The parameter `content` is a string with HTML code in it. The function above outputs the same html as the input but with the (fancybox) *a* tags surrounding all the child *img* tags.

So an input string like

```
"<div><img src='example.jpg'/></div>"
```

will output

```
"<div><a href='example.jpg' data-fancybox><img src='example.jpg'/></a></div>"
```

Can anyone improve this? I know too little about regex's to make this better.

Comment: Luca, I have this function that works, I just want to imporve it. I use this string in knockoutjs to bind with the html binding, so the html-string is rendered on the page.

Comment: Improvements can only be added in *context*. Without seeing what content (your HTML) looks like. Any improvements will be ineffective.

Comment: Clinton, I think the code is self explanatory, doesn't matter what content, just know that it is valid html (like the html-string of a webpage, of the html-string of a div with img as children), Example: var content = "<div><img src='example.jpg'/><img src='example2.jpg'/></div>"; This is a real short example because there's not enough characters in this comment box to make a full example. But the goal is to have an output string with the same html with the "img" tags surrounded by the (fancybox) "a" tags.

Comment: Clinton, I updated the post, this will indeed be a bit clearer, I was still in programming mode when I wrote this post :-)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this using strings instead of manipulating DOM elements?  Using regex on HTML is generally ill-advised.

Comment: @Amy I think he's doing web scrapping, so he get results from Ajax as html string. Well I guess. But would make things simpler.

Comment: Yes Amy, I use the knockoutjs framework and you can bind a string to an element with the html binding, this wil render the html-string as actual rendered html in the element you binded the html-string to. For more info see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html

Comment: @Amy and Clinton, it's not realy scraping, I get html content out of my db, this is content of a blog post, and bind it in javascript to my page. For the specific code see https://github.com/brechtb86/brechtbaekelandt.net/blob/master/brechtbaekelandt/wwwroot/js/view-models/post.js#L33 . This is actual working code for my blog, I don't want to spam but you can find a link of my blog on that github page, if you're interested.

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe you ask yourself why I just don't save those fancy box a tags in the db? Well, I want to keep the db clean and not add site specific html inserted into the post, so if I woud change the frontend, I don't have unecessary tags stored in the db, only the essential html of the post itself

Comment: I'd convert the string to a DOM object, do your html manipulation there, then feed that to knockout (after converting back to a string, if necessary).    Alternatively, do this DOM manipulation as a post-process step after knockout does its thing.  A bit roundabout, maybe, but almost anything's preferable to regexing HTML.

Comment: @DanielBeck interesting approach, how much impact would this have on performance (creating a DOM object for a blog post that could be hundreds of lines of html, basically almost a whole html page) because thats what I assume knockoutjs does at well, so it would be string => DOM object (manipulation) => string => (knockout) => DOM object

Comment: It would have an impact on performance, to be sure. How much of an impact really depends on the particulars, though (complex regex can be slow too); really the best you can do is try it and benchmark it and see whether it works well enough.

Comment: @DanielBeck it's also waaaay more code to write. Why wouldn't you recommend using regex to parse html in this case? I know for sure the string will be 100% valid html because it's generated by a wysiwyg editor (froala).

Comment: I went ahead and wrote up a full answer to that , since it was starting to grow beyond what a comment can contain :)  I see you've already settled on the post-processing approach, which you're right may be easier in your case, but maybe this'll still be useful for some future user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating HTML with regex is [notoriously problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  Changes that would be trivial in a DOM parser can be very difficult to create a robust regex for; and when regex fails, it fails silently, which makes errors easy to miss.  When working in regex you also have to be careful to handle all possible variations in markup such as whitespace, attribute order, quoting style, tag closing style, attribute contents that resemble html but which you don't want modified, etc.

As discussed exhaustively in the comment thread below, given enough time and effort it's certainly *possible* to handle all of these things in regex; but it leads to a complex, difficult to maintain regex -- and most importantly it's difficult to be certain your regex accommodates every possible valid markup variation.   DOM parsing handles all of this stuff automatically, and lets you work with the structured data directly instead of having to cope with all the possible variations in its string representation.

Therefore, if you need to make nontrivial changes to an HTML string, it's almost always best to convert your HTML into a true DOM tree, manipulate that using standard DOM methods, then (if necessary) convert it back into a string.  Fortunately it doesn't take a lot of code to do so.  Here's a simple vanilla JS demo:

```js
var htmlToElement = function(html) {
  var template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = html.trim();
  return template.content.firstChild;
};

var elementToHtml = function(el) {
  return el.outerHTML;
}

// Usage demo:
var string = "<div>This <b>is some</b> <i>html</i><img src='http://example.com'></div>";

var foo = htmlToElement(string);

// perform your DOM manipulation as needed on foo here. This would look much simpler if I wasn't so stubborn about avoiding jQuery these days, but here we are anyway:
foo.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('data-fancybox',true);
    link.setAttribute('href', img.getAttribute('src'));
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(link,img);
    link.appendChild(img);
});

// back to a string:
var bar = elementToHtml(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: I see the previous comments were deleted. I want to add that on SO there are hundreds of thousands of answers people post using simple regex to extract html info. Why there is some visceral notion that HTML can't be parsed at low level with regex is strange since W3C specs use regex in their specs. You miss the point, nobody can create a DOM with regex alone.  But, like with anything, the first level parse to unwrap elements is _tag_ parsing. Btw, saying `very difficult to create a robust regex for (see @sln's answer, for example); and when it fails, it fails catastrophically` is baloneyl

Comment: @sln, You're obviously unusually skilled with regex. That is great and you should continue to use whatever tools work best for you.  My experience has been that for nontrivial changes, regex tends to work fine on sample HTML data and then fail in the real world (such as if yours was run against HTML that included non-self-closing image tags, for example.) Obviously that particular one'd be a simple fix, but guaranteeing a regex will do what you want against real-world data is difficult: failures of that sort can be easy to miss, because no errors are thrown; things just quietly fail to match.

Comment: This isn't something you should be telling me, or _should_ you ? I don't think your last comment is for me, as I'm skilled, the easy fix is -> Regex mod (at the end): Remove `/>`, add `>(?:\s*</img\s*>)?`  or did you want to do that ? Here, `guaranteeing a regex will do what you want against real-world data is difficult` is totally invalid. Parsing html tags is as primitive and predictable as it gets. A _real-world_ cnn.com source stripped of html: https://regex101.com/r/mmalIt/1. There is more to this than I'm telling you, but I don't think you have an interest.

Comment: You might want to add the `/i` flag to the regex in your answer below, because as is it'll still fail to match lots of valid real-world html.  A trivial change, to be sure, but for something that's "as primitive and as predictable as it gets", it sure seems to need a lot of fiddling to get right...

Comment: I think adding an `(?i)` is a user choice, as was the choice to match just self contained closure. But, if you don't know regex, you might think this trivial.

Comment: Fair enough! We'll leave it at that, then.

Comment: Note that I think DOM and any processor will halt and throw errors at the first sign of mal-formed source. It should be noted that regex, for parsing tags will not. It is linear and single purposed, will not stop, nor will nor should validate the structure of tags and their closure validity, not nesting, etc...

Comment: If something's malformed I tend to prefer error messages over silent failure, yes.

Comment: (I mean, DOM parsers tend to be really forgiving, so that's kind of moot; but what you're listing there sound like *disadvantages* for regex to me.  I get that you have your preference, but I'm really not persuaded to agree. Sorry.)

Comment: The tag structure is fully validated via regex. Beyond that nothing else is validated about the html. Is that what you refer to ? Other things present problems. Markup can be hidden inside tags. For that reason, It's not recommended to search for a specific tag directly. That problem too can be handled via regex. Repair, replace, etc.. What I'm telling you just scratches the surface. If you examine any parser, there is low level regex used. I'm just bringing it out in the open for casual use.

Comment: Again, all of those problems -- markup-like content contained in attributes, attribute order, quote style, etc -- are things that DOM parsing takes care of for you automatically.  Those problems are the result of trying to use a string-parsing tool to manipulate structured data, instead of using the tool that was designed to manipulate that kind of structured data. Yes, with a sufficiently complex regex you can theoretically do anything at all. That doesn't mean it's the best approach for all tasks. The complexity of your regex just to maybe-reliably match *one single tag* speaks for itself.

Comment: `Again, all of those problems -- markup-like content contained in attributes, attribute order, quote style, etc --` Hey, nobody said they were problems the way you're saying it. Attributes and order, quote style, none of this is a problem. Hidden markup is not a problem but needs an extra regex clause alternation. This clause is the regex use in the link above to strip _all_ tags http://www.regex101.com/r/mmalIt/1. You know if you don't care about regular expressions and tag parsing, then do us a favor and stop knocking regex. The people that request help will appretiate that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm probably going to do DOM manipulation as @DanielBeck suggested. Once knouckout finished binding I will use $.wrap http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ to do my manipulation. I just hoped there was an easy way without using jquery, so if there are other suggestions please comment them.

Comment: Don't let people force you to code any certain way, if you want to use a regex, use it. I posted a reliable way.